# Multiindexed columns - Select inner

Tags: python, pandas

having a DataFrame like the following:

```
frame = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape((4, 3)),
   ....:                      index=[['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], [1, 2, 1, 2]],
   ....:                      columns=[['Ohio', 'Ohio', 'Colorado'],
   ....:                               ['Green', 'Red', 'Green']])
```

Whats the simplest way to select all columns with the color Green?

```
frame['Green']
```

... does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### [**`xs`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html)

This method was designed for this purpose.

```
frame.xs('Green', axis=1, level=1)
# frame.xs('Green', 1, 1)

     Ohio  Colorado
a 1     0         2
  2     3         5
b 1     6         8
  2     9        11
```

Or keep the level

```
frame.xs('Green', axis=1, level=1, drop_level=False)

     Ohio Colorado
    Green    Green
a 1     0        2
  2     3        5
b 1     6        8
  2     9       11
```

This is roughly equivalent to:
Obviously more complicated but interesting to see.

```
frame.loc[:, frame.columns.get_level_values(1) == 'Green']
```

Or

```
frame.loc[:, frame.columns.labels[1] == frame.columns.levels[1].get_loc('Green')]
```

---

#### [**`swaplevel`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html)

I don't like this way but good for informative purposes

```
frame.swaplevel(0, 1, 1).Green

     Ohio  Colorado
a 1     0         2
  2     3         5
b 1     6         8
  2     9        11
```

Answer (score 2):

This is multiple index , You can using `IndexSlice`

```
frame.loc[:,pd.IndexSlice[:,'Green']]
Out[506]: 
     Ohio Colorado
    Green    Green
a 1     0        2
  2     3        5
b 1     6        8
  2     9       11
```

Comment: At first I didn't realize it was a MultiIndex >.<

Comment: @piRSquared aha, when I see the list of list in column I just noticed that . :-)